# Putty closes on executing bash script

Tags: bash, putty

I am writing my first ever bash script, so excuse the noobie-ness.

It's called hello.bash, and this is what it contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
```

I did

```
chmod 700 hello.bash
```

to give myself permissions to execute.

Now, when I type

```
exec hello.bash
```

My putty terminal instantly shuts down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `exec` replaces the current process (your login shell) with the specified process (a bash script that prints "Hello World").  Once the hello world script has finished, you have no login shell and you are outta there.  Try `./hello.bash` rather than `exec hello.bash`.

Comment: @spong - thats an Answer really, you shoulda put it as one!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html) for exec:

> If command is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new process. If no command is specified, redirections may be used to affect the current shell environment.

So your script process runs in place of your terminal and when it exits, so does your terminal.  Just execute it instead:

```
./hello.bash
```